# why my form labels donesnt work with UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

django labels doesnt work with UpdateView, but labels from another model and Views works perfectly.

forms.py

```
    class Meta:
        model = Vacancy
        fields = "__all__"
        labels = {
                  'title': 'Название',
                  'skills': 'Требования',
                  'description': 'Описание',
                  'salary_min': 'Зарплата от',
                  'salary_max': 'Зарплата до',
                  }
```

views.py

```
class VacancyEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancies/vacancy-edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'skills', 'description', 'salary_min', 'salary_max']
    pk_url_kwarg = 'vacancy_id'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Applications'] = Application.objects.filter(vacancy_id=self.kwargs['vacancy_id'])
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not working with your form, you let Django construct a `ModelForm`, based on the `model` and the `fields`. You thus defined a form, but you have never *used* that form. The `UpdateView` used one it has constructed itself.

You can specify the form with the [**`form_class=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class) attribute:

```
class VacancyEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Vacancy
    form_class = VacancyForm
    template_name = 'vacancies/vacancy-edit.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'vacancy_id'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Applications'] = Application.objects.filter(vacancy_id=self.kwargs['vacancy_id'])
        return context
```

where *`VacancyForm`* is the form you defined in the `forms.py`.